# Apache2: How to restrict access to specific IP with ProxyPass?

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, access-control-list, mod-proxy, restrictions

I have an Apache2 Server configured as Reverse Proxy on my perimeter network.

There are a lot of VirtualHost configured with the ProxyPas directive.

For a specific one, I want to restrict access to a specific IP address.

This is an example:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:80>
    ServerAdmin email@domain.com
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    ServerAlias sub.domain.com
    ProxyPass / http://internal.domain.com:80/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://internal.domain.com:80/
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/my_log combined
    HostnameLookups Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerSignature On
    ProxyRequests Off
</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried to add this:

```
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 192.168.0.100
</Proxy>
```

but doesn't work because the Reverse Proxy does not preserve the remote IP address.

There is a way to use IP ACL with Apache configured as Reverse Proxy?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using: Reverse Proxy Request Headers (`X-Forwarded-For`)

- [mod_proxy - Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers)
- [mod_remoteip - Apache HTTP Server Version 2.5](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_remoteip.html#remoteipheader)

[Tutorial: Apache 2.4 as reverse proxy - LeaseWeb labs](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2014/12/tutorial-apache-2-4-transparent-reverse-proxy/) - covers second bullet point.

for `mod_proxy`:

```
LogFormat "%v %{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" pro
xy
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^.*\..*\..*\..*" forwarded
```